# Java: How do I take a snapshot (BufferedImage) from a Canvas without using paint()?

Tags: java, canvas, bufferedimage

(Java)
I have a canvas that represents an animation. I want to copy the contents of the canvas to a BufferedImage so I can save the snapshot to file. Every tutorial I found on the internet said to use paint() to copy the contents; unfortunately, this would produce new, different contents in my canvas the way I have it set up. There are randomly drawn lines, for instance, which would be recalculated if I called paint(). Is there any way to save the contents of a canvas to a BufferedImage without calling paint()?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the issue, but I think you are missing the point. to render the canvas, you need to call the paint() method, typically it will draw some shapes/image. How can you copy the canvas if it doesn't have a content ?

Comment: Check out these two links:  [1) This](http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/689/) is the usual way to capture a buffered image  [2) This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228685/paint-a-jpanel-to-a-bufferedimage-or-print-it-without-rendering-it-to-screen-fir) might be a viable workaround for you

Comment: *"There are randomly drawn lines, for instance, which would be recalculated if I called paint()"*.  You shouldn't have the randomness calculation inside `paint()`.  `paint()` can be called at arbitrary times by the window manager to repaint the window (including if it was obscured by another window). You should recalculate the "state" at your desired interval, and also force a repaint at your desired interval - but as two separate methods (e.g. `updateState()` and `paint()`).

Answer (score 1):

> ..save the contents of a canvas to a BufferedImage without calling paint()?

Draw the content to a `BufferedImage` prior to drawing the image to the `Canvas`.  When it comes time to save, simply use the cached image.

And think about joining us in the 3rd millennium and using Swing components.  Use `JPanel` & `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of the `Canvas` & `paint(Graphics)`.